# Relation between the kernel version and the codename

Tags: kernel

My current linux kernel version is

```
4.4.0-34-generic
```

and the

```
lsb_release -a

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Can I keep updating the kernel, without ever needing to change the codename? The latest Ubuntu is Yakkety Yak.

Would a combination of 4.4.0-34-generic and xenial also possible?
Or a combination of 4.4.0-34-generic and yakkety?

How are the ubuntu kernel releases related to the ubuntu main releases ( how is it actually called ) ?

Answer (score 0):

The codename corresponds to the release. So, Ubuntu 14.04 will always be referred to as "trusty".  The fact that you are using kernel 4.4.0-34-generic suggests that you are using the hardware enablement stack (HWE) that came with a later point release of trusty (14.04.5).
The roadmap for kernel releases for each Ubuntu release as well as other information regarding Ubuntu kernels may be found at the Ubuntu wiki site [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/FAQ). 
A list of Ubuntu kernels mapped to the mainline linux kernel is tracked [here](https://people.canonical.com/~kernel/info/kernel-version-map.html).